# Apache rewrite does not ignore specific directory rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this set up in my apache conf file

```html
RewriteRule ^(database)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have a phpmyadmin setup at example.com/database I also have a REST API setup where something like example.com/records/DELETE/{id} would lead you to example.com/index.php where the index.php handles parsing of the url

What I am expecting to happen is that typing in example.com/database it would take me to the phpmyadmin instance(basically ignoring the other rewrite rules)

if it is not example.com/database then it should go to the example.com/index.php

Thanks Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a condition to say redirect everything that isn't your database URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/database/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is the R stand for here?

Comment: @Joseph.Codes It means redirect. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: If I keep the R then the database url works but anything else I get a "Redirected to many times" if I remove the R the database URL stops working but everything else starts working

Comment: @Joseph.Codes Didn't really test. Try updated code.

Comment: I got it working just needed to add PT can you update your example to include that and I will accept

Comment: @Joseph.Codes I wouldn't expect you to need PT, I've never seen it used in fact. Have you tried the updated code?